# Notifications for Area 51 proposals announcements

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51, notifications

I'm a committer for an Area 51 proposal. A very important announcement<sup>1</sup> was posted last week, but I didn't get a notification of it. I'm wondering if the other 645 committers received that notification.

- At this time the announcement<sup>1</sup> only have my upvote.
- The announcement has a link<sup>2</sup> to a question that has 187 views.

[image: Announcements in Stack Overflow (in Spanish) proposal]

If they didn't receive the announcement notification, is there a way to request them to update their commitment to the proposal?

---

**UPDATE**
I subscribed to the proposal by RSS. The announcement nor the discussions are included in the proposal's RRS feed. I used the [RSS Subscription Extension (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-subscription-extensio/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd) to get the RSS URL and I'm using [Feedly](http://feedly.com) as RSS feed reader.

---

**Notes**

- <sup>1</sup>: After three years, finally the work to create an Stack Overflow site in Spanish has started. [Stack Overflow (in Spanish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish)
- <sup>2</sup>: [The "Stack Overflow in Spanish" Project is Underway!](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21519/the-stack-overflow-in-spanish-project-is-underway)

Comment: Umm... I don't think those were announcements, but rather discussion posts. You'll get an email when the beta starts anyway.

Comment: @Zizouz212. I added a screenshot showing the referred announcement.

Comment: There isn't currently a way to do this, but it is an excellent idea and potentially very powerful. I have submitted it as a feature-request and it is currently under review.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCartaino . I think that considering that the experience shows that the circumstances leads to put a proposal on hold for more than 12 months, could be very powerful to have someway to request a commitment update, i.e. one time every 12 months after the commit submission/update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I think many of you know, we don't have current support for Area 51, which is on a very old version of the code. While this idea is very good and we should have better default support to keep committers engaged with the proposals they're following, we don't have any plans to work on Area 51 in the near future, so we're going to decline this for the time being.

If there's some point in time that we decide to improve Area 51, we will be certain to find this and keep it in mind.